EPPlus ToDataTable Duplicate column name
I'm evaluating EPPlus package to handle excel files for processing by loading worksheets into .NET DataTables by the ToDataTable method.  However when I attempt to load a sheet that has duplicate column names in the header I get the following error message.
"Duplicate column name :...."
I've read that EPPlus supposedly handles duplicate column names by appending numbers on the duplicate names however that is not my experience, instead ToDataTable is crashing and I cannot find any suitable load options that will prevent it from crashing.
I tried setting the ColumnNameParsingStrategy option but none works.
//
// Summary:
//     Defines options for how to build a valid property or DataTable column name out
//     of a string
public enum NameParsingStrategy
{
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Preserve the input string as it is
    Preserve = 0,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Replace any spaces with underscore
    SpaceToUnderscore = 1,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Remove all spaces
    RemoveSpace = 2
}


I've read that EPPlus supposedly handles duplicate column names... it is recommended to include content of reference in the post and add the site URL for detailed researches.

I suggest you post more of your code.  This works fine for me using version 7.5.2 and Xunit:
[Fact]
public void DuplicateColumnNameTest()
{
    var fileInfo = new FileInfo("c:\\temp\\test1.xlsx");
    using var pkg = new ExcelPackage(fileInfo);
    var worksheet = pkg.Workbook.Worksheets.First();

    var table = worksheet.Tables.First();
    foreach (var column in table.Columns)
    {
        _testOutputHelper.WriteLine(column.Name);
    }

    var dataTable = table.ToDataTable();
    foreach (DataColumn column in dataTable.Columns)
    {
        _testOutputHelper.WriteLine(column.ColumnName);
    }
    _testOutputHelper.WriteLine("Finished");
}

Gives this in the output:
ColA
ColB 
ColB2
ColA
ColB
ColB2
Finished

Using this file:

